# How to create notification after listview receives new data from an online JSON file?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-notifications, auto-update

I have an online JSON file that shows the latest country earthquakes, the listView adapter in my app receives data from this JSON file and the refresh is manually by user`s swipe, but now I am adding an automatic and timely basis refresh mode to my list, the questions is:
**How can I create a system notification after a new quake is detected?**

Comment: You can use [Firebase push notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) to get notified.

Comment: @Rumit does firebase sent automatic notifications upon JSON update?

Answer (score 1):

Just **build** a **Notification** like this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle(textTitle)
    .setContentText(textContent)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

And then just **show it**

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

And for anything other extras check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

- In order for this to work you somehow should push when a new earthquake happens to your phone. If you **have backend**, you can send a push notification through the [cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqM3VBRCwARIsAKcekb2Ca0v8F5tf96m3_E17zZ2p1CQrXPs2ofDqENlNp-aliAhsYhCAE6saAu_2EALw_wcB).
- If you **don't have backend** just create a background service and pull data every now and then and when data says new earthquake jsut follow the notification creation from above.

Comment: thanks, but the main question is how to create a notification after new data has been received by the adapter, not how to create a notification.

Comment: Basically you just create a Notification as above when your are adding the item the adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Write this below code for sending System notification in your app while your data is loaded from network request.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("App Name / Title Message")
            .setContentText("Description Message hat data is updated")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.icon_color))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) // will show notification even you are in app
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    //you can use unique identification int number for notificationID instead of 1
```

putting this code block will show notification.

Comment: I am using AsyncTask for network request, shall I put it in postExecute phase?